# Create F# console application around C# static class

Tags: javascript, c#, f#

I'm trying to create a console application wrapper around a `C#` based `dll`. I want to use `F#` to do this. I'm using `UnionArgParser` to parse the arguments. I've dabbled in `F#` before, but it has been a while. I will be calling the console application from `node.js`. I looked at `edge.js` but wasn't sure I would want to go that route since it seems more complicated way to interact and it appeared some people had issues getting it to work - so I thought the way I'm planning on going about it might be more robust and simple.

In `JavaScript` I would do something like this (which I did for some `signalR` code I was working on):

```
var methods = ['method1', 'method2'].reduce((acc, methodName) => {
  acc[methodName] = (...args) => {return [methodName].concat(args)}
  return acc
}, {})

// call method, with a predefined invoker function
invoke(methods.method1('arg1', 2))
```

So, for F#, I was thinking I would something similar, but everything will be strongly typed, so I'm not sure how to go about it. I was thinking something like this:

```ml
let invoker methodName args =
  match methodName with
  | "getSomeValues" ->
    toJSON(Invoke(SomeFramework.GlobalFunctions.GetSomeValues, args))
  | "getSomeOtherValues" ->
    toJSON(Invoke(SomeFramework.GlobalFunctions.GetSomeOtherValues, args))
  | _ -> """{"Error": "Incorrect function given."}"""
```

Of course, with F# maybe I should go with something more strongly typed. I'm not even really sure. I guess I'm looking to be pointed in the right direction, then I could figure it out on my own. But it is all looking a little Greek to me right now.

[This blog](http://fortysix-and-two.blogspot.com/2008/10/how-to-invoke-method-with-type.html), might be something I could use, but it is pretty old (2008), so there might be better ways to go about it now.

**Update**

So, the input that I will receive from the console will be something like this.

```ml
consoleWrapper.exe --methodname method1 arg1 2
```

or I could do

```ml
consoleWrapper.exe --methodname method1 --arg1Value arg1 --arg2Value 2
```

`UnionArgParser` will give me the primitively typed values defined in a `union` that I call like so:

```ml
let arg1 = (results.GetResults <@ arg1Value @>).[0]
```

Comment: Generally speaking, in F# you would want to define types.  Only use weakly typed stuff when you absolutely have to (which is almost never).  I think we'll need more details on the structure of the data you have to give better information, but I'm going to guess you want to use discriminated unions.

Comment: OK, I'll update with more details.

Comment: @mydogisbox OK, I updated it with how I'm getting the arguments and how they can be strongly typed.

Comment: You may not need a fancy arguments parser library to parse command-line options; here's an example of how simple you can do it with F#: https://github.com/ploeh/ZeroToNine/blob/master/Src/Zero29/Args.fs#L26-L44

Comment: Thanks @MarkSeemann, I'm actually using `UnionArgParser`. It's pretty nice. I'll check it out though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I ended up just using `reflection` by getting the `typeof<MyFramework.MyStaticClass>` `Type` then using the `GetMethod` method and `GetParameters` to get the parameters of the method. I then mapped over the parameters from the console app and the parameter method results and `Convert.ChangeType` to the array of console parameters. Then I `info.Invoke(null, args)` and got my result.

Not as strongly typed as F# normally is but it is already typed in C#, so either way I would be throwing errors since the console won't be strongly typed, no reason to over build it. If it was mostly native I think it would make sense to make sure the typing is stronger.

Now, to convert the result to `JSON`.